# Ошибка в запросе SQL

Tags: php, mysql

Так работает

```
$tab=$_GET[tab];
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE `$tab` (`id` int(20), `title` varchar(250), `data` varchar(200), `chpu` varchar(200), `content` longtext, `anons` text, `desc` text, `keys`   text, `avtor` varchar(200), `cat` varchar(200));");
```

А когда дописываю `AUTO INCREMENT`, то не создается таблица.
Так не работает

```
 $tab=$_GET[tab];
$res=mysql_query("CREATE TABLE `$tab` (`id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `title` varchar(250), `data` varchar(200), `chpu` varchar(200), `content` longtext, `anons` text, `desc` text, `keys` text, `avtor` varchar(200), `cat` varchar(200));");
```

А когда убираешь `AUTO INCREMENT`, тогда нормально.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Автоинкрементный столбец должен быть объявлен первичным ключом.

```
CREATE TABLE `$tab` (`id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `title` varchar(250), `data` varchar(200), `chpu` varchar(200), `content` longtext, `anons` text, `desc` text, `keys` text, `avtor` varchar(200), `cat` varchar(200), PRIMARY KEY (id));
```